# Uploading Downloading of large size file to Google Drive giving error

Tags: android, http, google-drive-api

I am Creating a small Apps from that user can upload his MS office file to his registered mail ID G_Drive account from android device.
and export that file into PDF Format.

for that i taken help form below link :

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#examples

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents

i created application, and its working fine for small size(< 1MB) file, but when i am sending large size to the g_Drive than i am getting below errors:

```
java.io.exception Unexpected End of Stream
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

i tried for Resumable upload, but the insert method doesn't have parameter to set this.
if am setting the upload type to resumable with

```
service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).set("upload type", "resumable");
```

or

```
Insert insertService = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).setConvert(true);
insertService.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(false);         insertService.getMediaHttpUploader().setChunkSize(MediaHttpUploader.DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE);
file = insertService.execute();
```

than also its generating same errors.

same case with downloading also.....

please send me some solutions...for this...

Answer (score 1):

Don't use basic upload for files larger than 5MB.

You need to set the content length of the media content before starting to upload. Otherwise, it's likely that Google endpoint can't recognize the upload's being finished and it waits until the socket is being timed out.

```
InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("image/jpeg", new   BufferedInputStream(
    new FileInputStream(UPLOAD_FILE)));
mediaContent.setLength(UPLOAD_FILE.length());

Insert insert = drive.files().insert(fileMetadata, mediaContent);
MediaHttpUploader uploader = insert.getMediaHttpUploader();
uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);
uploader.setProgressListener(new FileUploadProgressListener());
insert.execute();
```

There is actually a complete Android based resumable upload sample on [[1]](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/drive-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/drive/cmdline/DriveSample.java?repo=samples&r=08555cd2a27be66dc97505e15c60853f47d84b5a).

Comment: I Added
java.io.File tempFile = new java.io.File(DocxFile);
InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(tempFile)));
mediaContent.setLength(tempFile.length());
Insert insert = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent);
insert.setConvert(true);
insert.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(false);
insert.getMediaHttpUploader().setProgressListener(new FileUploadProgressListener());
file = insert.execute();
but its giving error for large size file.

Comment: A bit offtopic perhaps but pertinent to the matter: Where in this code or in the sample you mention is the "resumable" part being handled? All I see is inserts being made in chunks, but if one fails, won't we have to restart it and start all over again?