# Uploading File in Google Drive with setConvert(true);

Tags: google-drive-api

i am trying to upload file in GoogleDrive with setConvert(true);
my code is as follows:

```
InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(mimeType, new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)));
mediaContent.setLength(filename.length());
Insert insert = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent);
insert.setConvert(true);        
insert.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(false);
insert.getMediaHttpUploader().setProgressListener(new FileUploadProgressListener());
file = insert.execute();
```

its giving me below error

IOException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
{
    "code": 500,
    "errors": [
    {
        "domain": "global",
        "message": "Internal Error",
        "reason": "internalError"
    }
   ],
   "message": "Internal Error"
}

Comment: What's on the body? Does it work without conversion is set to true? I'm not able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: body is a com.google.api.service.drive.model.File type variable, which contain metadata about the file like title, description, mimetype etc.Its working fine without using setConvert(true), but if i am not using this than file.getExportLinks().get(PDF_FILE_TYPE); is returning NULL, and without PDF download URL i can't download the PDF of the inserted File.

Comment: If it's an unconvertible mimeType, there may be no export links. What's your mime-type?

Comment: mime-type is application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document or application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet or application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation, i am not using unconvertible mime type because the earlier code is working fine for small size files, but for big size files it was giving error as i asked on [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970423/uploading-downloading-of-large-size-file-to-google-drive-giving-error).

Comment: Conversion is an async process I guess and the conversion is probably not completed when upload is done. Let me check back with the team...