# cannot upload to google drive from my android app

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm writing an adroid app that used to upload a chosen image

to the users' google drive.

I have cloned the code from git to another machine and then the image won't upload any more.

I get a `com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown` exception. but it's caught here:

```
 } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

[image]

```
      if(fileContent.length() > 5 * 1024 * 1024)
      {
          // Resumable Uploads when the file size exceeds a file size of 5 MB.
          // check link : 
          // 1) https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/drive-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/drive/cmdline/DriveSample.java?repo=samples&r=08555cd2a27be66dc97505e15c60853f47d84b5a
          // 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970423/uploading-downloading-of-large-size-file-to-google-drive-giving-error

          AbstractGoogleClientRequest<File> insert = mDriveService.files().insert(body, mediaContent);
          MediaHttpUploader uploader = insert.getMediaHttpUploader();
          uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);
          uploader.setProgressListener(new FileUploadProgressListener());
          destFile = (File) insert.execute();

      }   
      else
      {
          // Else we go by Non Resumable Uploads, which is safe for small uploads.
          destFile = mDriveService.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
      }
```

Any hints what i can check and verify (maybe missing libraries references?)

[image]

[image]

I have thought it's because I upload an image from external SD, but even if i choose from local phone SD it throws same exception

Comment: Are you sure no things you're insterting like `body` and `mediaContent` are null?

Comment: checked already. non-null