# cannot upload to google drive from my android app com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-authentication

I'm writing an adroid app that used to upload a chosen image

to the users' google drive.

I have cloned the code from git to another machine and then the image won't upload any more.

I get a `com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown` exception. but it's caught here:

```
 } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

[image]

```
      if(fileContent.length() > 5 * 1024 * 1024)
      {
          // Resumable Uploads when the file size exceeds a file size of 5 MB.
          // check link : 
          // 1) https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/drive-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/drive/cmdline/DriveSample.java?repo=samples&r=08555cd2a27be66dc97505e15c60853f47d84b5a
          // 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970423/uploading-downloading-of-large-size-file-to-google-drive-giving-error

          AbstractGoogleClientRequest<File> insert = mDriveService.files().insert(body, mediaContent);
          MediaHttpUploader uploader = insert.getMediaHttpUploader();
          uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);
          uploader.setProgressListener(new FileUploadProgressListener());
          destFile = (File) insert.execute();

      }   
      else
      {
          // Else we go by Non Resumable Uploads, which is safe for small uploads.
          destFile = mDriveService.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
      }
```

this is my login to drive code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE));
    startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

}

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
        String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
        if (accountName != null) {
          credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
          mDriveService = getDriveService(credential);
          saveFileToDrive();
        }
      }
      break;

      //second try to upload, if credentials were wrong
    case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        saveFileToDrive();
      } else {
        startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
      }
      break;
    case CAPTURE_IMAGE:
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        saveFileToDrive();
      }
    }
  }
```

Any hints what i can check and verify (maybe missing libraries references?)

I have thought it's because I upload an image from external SD, but even if i choose from local phone SD it throws same exception

Comment: Where did you log in into Google Drive?

Comment: And you are really sure that your credentials are right and that you first initialize your mDriveService?

Comment: how can they be wrong? I choose my drive account which work in the official app. this is the first and only place I initialize `mDriveService`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that i had to re-register my app

with a new SHA1 key for the new machine which creates and sign the apk